# Sal select statement to filter results

Tags: sql-server

I have joined together tables but the data has some duplicates by design. To simple the example below

### User    address

User1   100 main st.

User1   999 everyone St.

User2   400 elm st.

User2   999 everyone St.

User3   300 pine st.

User3   999 everyone St.

User4   999 everyone St.

How would I get every user only once and the one address getting the preferred address (instead of the generic 999 everyone st. that everyone gets).

User1      100 main st.

User2      400 elm st.

User3      300 pine st.

User4     999 everyone St.

Answer (score 0):

As I am unsure of how your tables are built, the answer might the a little too general, but I am pretty sure that selecting your values distinctively might fix your problem.

You would do it like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER.ID, STREET.STREET_NUMBER
FROM USER
  INNER JOIN --the rest of your code...
```

That way, when you use distinct, it will only display the next row if the id of the user is different. Effectively, that will only display the first address row of each user, which is the actual value that you want to have, instead of displaying both the default row and the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row number with `Partition by` like this

```sql
Select userId, address from (
Select userId , address, row_number() over(partition by userId order by address) rw
From your_join_tables) t
Where t.rw=1
```

Comment: Thanks. this put me on the right track and I figured it out.